# Dask worker hangs after missing dep key

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

In a distributed GKE dask cluster, I have one graph that stalls with the traceback below.  The worker dashboard continues reporting the same constant high value for cpu, while the GKE dashboard shows near-zero CPU for the pod.  The "last seen" value of the worker dashboard becomes many minutes.  After 15 minutes I kill the GKE pod, yet the dask scheduler still indicates the worker exists and keeps the task assigned to it.   The scheduler seems to be wedged regarding this task - no progress is made, nor is any cleanup or restarting of the failing work unit.

I am using dask/distributed 2020.12.0, dask-gateway 0.9.0, and xarray 0.16.2.

What can cause a key to go missing?

How does one debug or workaround the underlying issue here?

Edit:

- For each run of the same graph, a different key is in the traceback.  Wedged workers for a single run show the same key in their tracebacks.
- With enough patience/retries, the graph can succeed.
- I am using an auto-scaling cluster with pre-emptible nodes, though the problem persists even if I remove auto-scaling and set a fixed number of nodes.
- I've seen this on different workloads.  The current workload I'm struggling with creates a dask dataframe from two arrays like this:

```
    image_chunks = image.to_delayed().ravel()
    labels_chunks = labels.to_delayed().ravel()

    results = []
    for image_chunk, labels_chunk in zip(image_chunks, labels_chunks):
        offsets = np.array(image_chunk.key[1:]) * np.array(image.chunksize)
        result = dask.delayed(stats)(image_chunk, labels_chunk, offsets, ...)
        results.append(result)
    ...
    dask_df = dd.from_delayed(results, meta=df_meta)
    dask_df = dask_df.groupby(['label', 'kind']).sum()
```

Example traceback #1

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 2627, in execute
    self.ensure_communicating()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 1880, in ensure_communicating
    to_gather, total_nbytes = self.select_keys_for_gather(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 1985, in select_keys_for_gather
    total_bytes = self.tasks[dep].get_nbytes()
KeyError: 'xarray-image-bc4e1224600f3930ab9b691d1009ed0c'
```

```
tornado.application - ERROR - Exception in callback functools.partial(<bound method IOLoop._discard_future_result of <tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOLoop object at 0x7fac3d04f4f0>>, <Task finished name='Task-143' coro=<Worker.execute() done, defined at /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/worker.py:2524> exception=KeyError('xarray-image-bc4e1224600f3930ab9b691d1009ed0c')>)
```

Example traceback #2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 741, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 765, in _discard_future_result
    future.result()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 2146, in gather_dep
    await self.query_who_has(dep.key)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 2218, in query_who_has
    self.update_who_has(response)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 2227, in update_who_has
    self.tasks[dep].who_has.update(workers)
KeyError: "('rechunk-merge-607c9ba97d3abca4de3981b3de246bf3', 0, 0, 4, 4)"
```

Comment: It might be useful to include the workload you were trying to execute. Does this happen consistently, and is it always the same key in the error message? Please list your current versions of dask, distributed and xarray.

Comment: Added additional info as per @mdurant

Comment: I am seeing lots of KeyErrors everywhere, so the fact that I see them on my hung-up worker could be superfluous.